# Converting string to float - java vs javascript

Tags: javascript, java, floating-point, precision

I am trying to correctly convert (parse) a string to float in java, for the number 5755.1115, example:

```
float fl = new BigDecimal("5755.1115").floatValue();
float fl = (float)5755.1115d;
```

The issue is that it always prints 5755.1113. It seems it loses precision (I also tried using MathcContext(10) for example but didn't work)

But if I try this in javascript it seems it is working:

```
var fl = parseFloat('5755.1115');
var str = "" + fl.toPrecision(8);
console.log("number: " + str);
```

It prints the number correctly even if I don't use toPrecision() function.

Can anyone explain how can I achieve this also in Java?

EDIT:
My mistake, I forgot to specify that I do not want to use double because I need to keep the data transmission at minimum.

Comment: Why are you comparing Java and JavaScript?

Comment: Seems pretty evident that `5755.1113` is the closest `float` to `5755.1115`. You could use a `double` instead if it's not precise enough.

Comment: I think it's because JavaScript only has double and 5755.1115 has too much precision for a float.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I do not want to use double because I need to keep the data transmission at minimum. (I edited my post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the java side: this here

```
float fl = new BigDecimal("5755.1115").floatValue();
```

is basically **pointless**. You first create a BigDecimal object (which allows for *arbitrary* precision) - to then turn that precise representation into a much "less precise" float value. You could as well write

```
float fl = 5755.1115f;
```

instead. Either you want to spend the overhead for "precise" BigDecimal - or you are happy with ordinary Java float floating point semantics. But mixing those two concepts like you are doing here is, as said: pointless.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript only knows doubles.
Calling toPrecision(8) on a JavaScript double won't change that.

[Not just in Java,] a float isn't big enough to store 5755.1115 accurately.

> Can anyone explain how can I achieve this also in Java?

Use a double instead of a float if you need the extra precision.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I do not want to use double because I need to keep the data transmission at minimum. (I edited my post)

Comment: A float isn't big enough so you have to accept the loss in precision then or use something else.